# Task.WaitAll() not working as expected

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, task, async-await

I'm trying to figure out how to work with the Task class. In the past I have always used the regular Thread class, but I'm trying to grasp all of the asynchronous programming...

As an example, I created a main Winforms application that has all the code.
The relevant code for my problem is:

```
//Relevant delegates
public delegate void MethodAction(int num);
public delegate void MethodConversion();
public delegate void OnCompletionAction(string completiontext);

//Button user presses
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Clear();
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();
    Sync.RunAsync3(calcSim);
}

//The method that simulates a calculation by adding a sleep
//the input param threadlength is just to allow threads to take longer than others
//since I'm multithreading, I have to invoke the writing code on the windows RichTextbox control
private void calcSim(int threadlength)
{
    string threadname = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //Thread calc should take 3s
    {
        Thread.Sleep(300 + threadlength);
        richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodConversion)(() =>
                            { 
                                richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("Thread: {0}\tVersion: {1}\n", threadname, (i + 1).ToString())); 
                            }));
    }
}

//Class that contains the different processing methods
public static class Sync
{
    public static event OnCompletionAction OnProcCompletion;

    public static void RunAsync3(MethodAction doM)
    {
        Task[] t = new Task[4];
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            t[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)(() => { doM(50 * i); }));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(t);
        if (OnProcCompletion != null) OnProcCompletion("RunSync method finished");
    }
}
```

The problem lies within Task.WaitAll(t)... For some reason, which I can't figure out, it completely blocks on that line and doesn't respond anymore. If I omit that line, the form gets updated in realtime and the execution take about 3 seconds.

My question is: why isn't Task.WaitAll() blocking the UI thread for 3 seconds before releasing it and allowing the rest of the code to execute?

**I know it should be blocking the UI for some time (until all threads are calculated), but it blocks the complete app endlessly. It seems to be waiting forever?**

**EDIT**

I've been suggested to use WhenAll instead of WaitAll. I have rewritten RunAsync3 as follows:

```
public static void RunAsync3(MethodAction doM)
{
    Task[] t = new Task[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        t[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)(() => { doM(50 * i); }));
    }
    //Task.WaitAll(t); -> deadlock
    Task.WaitAll(new Task [] { Task.WhenAll(t) });
    if (OnProcCompletion != null) OnProcCompletion("RunSync method finished");
}
```

But this is still getting deadlocked...? I might be using the WhenAll incorrectly?

**EDIT 2**

Because everybody claiming that I was blocking the UI thread were right, I decided to try this another way: by running a new thread as my calling thread inside the UI thread (so that blocking now would occur on my thread instead of UI thread). This works, but is obviously not the best way to do this!

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodConversion)(() => richTextBox1.Clear()));
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        Sync.RunAsync3(calcSim);
    }));
    t.Start();
}
public static void RunAsync3(MethodAction doM)
{
    Task[] t = new Task[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        t[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)(() => { doM(50 * i); }));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(t);
   //Task.WaitAll(new Task [] { Task.WhenAll(t) });
   if (OnProcCompletion != null) OnProcCompletion("RunSync method finished");
}
```

Comment: Because Task.WaitAll(t); runs in the UI thread!

Comment: Main.WaitAll + Worker.Invoke on main = block

Comment: I know it should be blocking the UI thread, that isn't the problem. The problem is that it never continues with the rest of the code. It seems that it is waiting endlessly!

Comment: Since you're trying to "Invoke" something on the main thread which is in a waitstate, from a worker?

Comment: @MarvinSmit and how would I fix this?

Comment: You should consider `await Task.WhenAll(...);`

Comment: MarvinSmit is right. You cannot block the UI thread and expect Invoke to do something on the blocked UI thread.

Comment: An alternative would be to push the actions you are doing onto a stack, and after the waitall (which will then work since you are not trying to call the main thread anymore) pop & execute the build stack

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're causing a deadlock.

The UI thread is waiting for 4 tasks to be completed.

On the other hand, those 4 tasks, running `calcSim` are trying to invoke code on the UI thread -> Deadlock.

You should be using `Task.WhenAll()` instead. That method will return a new task that will be marked as completed when all your for tasks have completed. If you await that task, your UI thread will be freed, and so `calcSim` will be able to invoke code on the UI thread, avoiding a deadlock.

**Update**

You're using it wrong. You're still using `WaitAll`, which is a blocking call. You should *replace* it with `WhenAll`.

```
await Task.WhenAll(t);
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the supplied tasks have
>   completed.

By calling `await` on the result, your UI thread will be free - until all 4 tasks complete. When that happens, your `RunAsync3` method will resume.

Comment: now this seems like a plausible answer! How would I go on about fixing it?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a possible fix. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I'm still getting deadlocked... I have updated my question with my attempts that you suggested, but everything remains blocked... Perhaps I'm using WhenAll wrong?

Comment: Perfect! I was hoping to omit the async & await keywords until I grasped Task, Threadpool and Parallel but in this case I don't think there's a way around it. I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: What is the official definition of "UI thread"? MSDN doesn't have it.

Comment: @Love when people people say "UI thread", they mean the thread which is running the "message pump"/"message loop". This is a loop (implemented by the framework) that continously polls Windows for any new UI events, such as mouse clicks, scroll, keystrokes, etc, and then calls the appropriate event handler implemented in your code. In the OP's code, the message pump will call the `button4_click` handler synchronously if detects the button was pressed - which means the message pump and the handlers all run on the same thread - the UI thread

Comment: @dcastro,thanks. But MSDN doesn't mention `Task.WaitAll`can't used in "UI thread" explicitly. I guess that I missed something but no clue.

Comment: @Love It doesn't say that, because `Task.WaitAll` **can** be used on the UI thread :) that's not the problem here. The problem' is that the OP is invoking a blocking call (`Task.WaitAll` pauses the current thread until the tasks are complete) **while** the child tasks are trying to run some code on the calling thread. In other words, you have one thread paused waiting for child threads, and the child threads are paused waiting for the main thread to be freed up -> deadlock. The problem isn't specific to `Task.WaitAll` or the UI thread - it applies to any blocking call on any thread.

Answer (score 1):

`Task.WaitAll` blocks and waits for all task to complete and you are calling it on the UI thread.

All your task are trying to call `richTextBox1.Invoke` (in the UI thread) but your UI thread is blocked in `Task.WaitAll`. Deadlock.

Answer (score -1):

Because it waits as your threads finish. They run exactly 3 seconds 300X10

Comment: But it waits forever and not just until my threads finish. That is the problem! They SHOULD run around 3 seconds and then release the UI block, but that never happens. My app remains in a blocking state forever...