# Why my windows form freezes and deadlock?

Tags: c#, winforms, tpl-dataflow

For my producer-consumer application, I clicked the button to trigger it. However it freezes. The basic idea of the project is to find how many even numbers in the queue when clicking Start button. Click Cancel button to stop it. I want to print the result on the console. But both are not working, which means no output(empty on the screen). It may be deadlock? Anyway the screen freezes.

The entire clean code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CancellationTokenStop
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static BufferBlock<int> m_Queue = new BufferBlock<int>(new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 1000 });
        private static int evenNumber;
        private static CancellationTokenSource cTokenSource;
        private static CancellationToken cToken;
        private static Object obj = new object();
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool AllocConsole();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AllocConsole();
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           cTokenSource.Cancel();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                cToken = cTokenSource.Token;
                var producer = Producer();
                var consumer = Consumer();

                Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer).Wait();
                Report();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                Console.Read();
            }
        }

        static async Task Producer()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                // Send a value to the consumer and wait for the value to be processed
                await m_Queue.SendAsync(i);
            }
            // Signal the consumer that there will be no more values
            m_Queue.Complete();
        }

        static async Task Consumer()
        {
            try
            {
                var executionDataflowBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
                };
                var consumerBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(x =>
                {
                    DoWork(x, cToken);
                    if (x % 2 == 0)
                        // Increment the counter in a thread-safe way
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref evenNumber);

                }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

                // Link the buffer to the consumer
                using (m_Queue.LinkTo(consumerBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }))
                {
                    // Wait for the consumer to finish.
                    // This method will exit after all the data from the buffer was processed.
                    await consumerBlock.Completion;
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.Read();
            }
        }

        static void DoWork(int x, CancellationToken cToken)
        {
            cToken.Register(() =>
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Stop at "+x);
            });
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        public static void Report()
        {
             Console.WriteLine("There are {0} even numbers", evenNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

The producer part is simple, it just sends data to a `BufferBlock`. Consumer part is complicated, using `ActionBlock` and pass a cancellation token.

The expected result is stored in the variable `evenNumber`.

Comment: "freezes" or "deadlocks" in a GUI application pretty much always means you've blocked the main thread in the program, the one that handles all of the drawing and user input. If you actually search the web or StackOverflow, you'll find lots of existing discussion on the topic, along with good solutions.

Comment: Well because you specifically said it should Wait(). Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer).Wait(); blocks your UI, better if you should await your call on producer and consumer

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766535/task-waitall-not-working-as-expected

Comment: @RonaldEstacion, If I remove `Wait`, the output is wrong.

Comment: @HuiZhao Go look for Task ContinueWith, you can chain actions using that, I'm still installing my VS so i can't provide you with a mock code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blocking your UI in your button click with the `.Wait` you need to `await` instead.

```
    private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cToken = cTokenSource.Token;
            var producer = Producer();
            var consumer = Consumer();

            await Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer);
            Report();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```